# How do I make a list that shows what keys I took from a dictionary

Tags: python

```
    Books = {"1":"Percy Jackson", "2":"Harry Potter","3":"Eragon","4":"Science for Dummies", "5": 
    "Encyclopedia of Knowledge"}
    for choice in Books:
        choices = []
        choices2 = []
        picking = input("Please take a book.Please pick the book number: ")
        picking = int(picking)
        question = input("Do you want to continue: ")
        if 6 > picking:
            picking = str(picking)
            print(Books[picking])
            choices.append(Books[picking])
            choices2.append(choices[:])
        else:
            print("Error")
        if question == "yes":
            continue
        else:
            print("Checkout")
            print(choices)
            print(choices2)
            break
```

I am new so the formatting might be off. The whole point of this was to make a "Library" and have 5 types of books. I then have to make the code add a thing at the bottom that says, what books the person got. The problem is that the .append keeps destroying the one before it in the for loop. Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: The whole code doesn't make any sense. You basically loop through all the books available and reset the `choices` (and `choices2`?) to an empty list right before you ask for a book number.

Comment: Move the `choices = []` and `choices2 = []` out of the for loop. In every iteration, the empty lists get assigned to those two variables hence overwriting the previously added values

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
choices = []
choices2= []
```

outside the `for` loop or it will keep making new empty lists.